# React + Redux: component not rerendering on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm making a multiplayer game on React and using Colyseus.js as my multiplayer API. The thing is that I need to display all connected players in the lobby:

```js
export default function Lobby() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const gameState = useSelector(state => state.roomState);
    const history = useHistory();

    // Creating array to display all connected players
    let playersArray = [];
    if(Object.entries(gameState).length !== 0) {
        playersArray = Object.values(gameState.players.toJSON());

    }
    // Check if game has started
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('gamestarted:', gameState.gameStarted);
        if(gameState.gameStarted){
            history.push('/game')
        }
    }, [gameState.gameStarted]);
    return (
        <PageFrame>
            <Grid
                container
                direction="column"
                alignItems="center"
                className={classes.root}
                spacing={2}
            >
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Typography className={classes.gameTitle}>
                        {(gameState != null) ? gameState.gameName : <CircularProgress />}
                    </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    Waiting for all players to join...
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    Connected Players: {playersArray.length}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    {playersArray.map((data, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Chip
                                key={index}
                                label={data.party}
                                className={classes.chip}
                                style={{"--color": green[500]}}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </PageFrame>
    );
}
```

I use `useSelector` to get state I received from Colyseus.js and dispatched like this (in another component which has `Lobby` as a child in `<Route>`):

```
const joinRoom = (id, partyName, actions) => {
        client.joinById(id, {partyName, id}).then(room => {
            dispatch({type: GAME_ROOM, payload: room });
            dispatch({type: RECONNECT_PARAMS, payload: {roomId: room.id, sessionId: room.sessionId} });
            // Redirect to lobby
            history.push('/lobby')
            {...}
            room.onStateChange((state) => {
                console.log("the room state has been updated:", state);
                // HERE DISPATCHING RECEIVED STATE
                dispatch({type: GAME_STATE, payload: state });
            });
            room.onLeave((code) => {
                {...}
        });
    }
```

`state` from server has property `players` with object, which has keys with player names I need to display.
My reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    joinDetails:{
        gameCode: '',
        partyName: ''
    },
    sessionParams: {
        roomId: "",
        sessionId: "",
    },
    room: {},
    roomState: {},
    scoreChange: null,
    totalChange: null,
    playerState:{
        showResults: false,
        questions: [],
        totalBudget: 5000,
        totalGlobalBudget: 5000,
        budget: [],
        activeStep: 0,
        stepCompleted: [false,false,false,false,false],
        decisions: [-1,-1,-1,-1],

    }

};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case JOIN_FORM:
            return {...state, joinDetails: action.payload};
        case GAME_ROOM:
            return {...state, room: action.payload};
        case GAME_STATE:
            return {...state, roomState: action.payload};
        case RECONNECT_PARAMS:
            return {...state, sessionParams: action.payload};
        case CHANGE_STEP:
            if(action.payload === 'add'){
                return {...state, playerState: {...state.playerState, activeStep: state.playerState.activeStep + 1}}}
            else{
                return {...state, playerState: {...state.playerState, activeStep: state.playerState.activeStep - 1}}}
        case COMPLETE_STEP:
            return {...state, playerState: {...state.playerState, stepCompleted: action.payload}};
        case SET_BUDGET:
            return {...state, playerState: {...state.playerState, budget: action.payload}};
        case SET_QUESTIONS:
            return {...state, playerState: {...state.playerState, questions: action.payload}};
        case SET_TOTAL_BUDGET:
            if(action.payload.add !== undefined){
                return {...state, playerState: {...state.playerState, totalBudget: state.playerState.totalBudget + action.payload.add}}
            }
            else{
                return {...state, playerState: {...state.playerState, totalBudget: action.payload}};
            }

        case SET_GLOBAL_BUDGET:
            if(action.payload.add !== undefined){
                return {...state, playerState: {...state.playerState, totalGlobalBudget: state.playerState.totalGlobalBudget + action.payload.add}}
            }
            else{
                return {...state, playerState: {...state.playerState, totalGlobalBudget: action.payload}}
            }
        case SET_DECISIONS:
            return {...state, playerState: {...state.playerState, decisions: action.payload}};
        case SET_CHANGES:
            return {...state, scoreChange: action.payload.change, totalChange: action.payload.total};
        case SHOW_RESULTS:
            return {...state, playerState: {...state.playerState, showResults: action.payload}};
        case CLEAR_STATE:
            return {...state, playerState: {}};

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default rootReducer;
```

**The problem is that player list does not update after new players join.** I can confirm that:

- I receive state from server with new players
- I dispatch this state to redux successfully (I see it through redux devtools)
- It looks like Lobby() is simply not rerendering, dispite having `useSelector` which works, because each player sees the list of players who joined before him.

I tried looking for mutated state, but it looks to me I everything is good there. It's my first redux project, so maybe I'm missing something.
One suspicious thing I notice in redux devtools that sometimes(!) the latest state propagates trough all previous states in devtools view, e.g. "Diff" tab shows that all same actions resulted in no changes except the first one has changed state to final form, for example:

Actual changes:

- ACTION changed some property to a
- ACTION changed some property to b
- ACTION changed some property to c

Shown changes (but they became like this only after third time):

- ACTION changed some property to a, some property to b and some
  property to c
- ACTION changed nothing
- ACTION changed nothing

Not sure if this normal or causes my issue.

If you need aditional code let me know.

Thanks.

EDIT: Changed some names, as per advice in comments, issue still perisits.

EDIT 2: The problem seems directly related to `useSelector`: currently I have

```
gameState = useSelector(state => state.roomState)
```

but if I select the whole state, everything works, component rerenders.

```
gameState = useSelector(state => state)
```

this is far from ideal: now I need to call `gameState.roomState.something` instead of `gameState.something` everywhere. How it can be that `useSelector` doesn't recognize the change of particular part of state and only recognize the change of whole state?

Comment: Try to change useSelector to - { const gameState = useSelector(state => state); } or to state.joinDetalis etc from your initialState

Comment: @HagaiHarari Do you mean just return the whole state? Now I'm returning "state" key from state, maybe the naming is causing the problem?

Comment: Ok, so I had a better look at your code and saw in your intialState "state" method that state.state refers to.     But maybe call it differently as "myState", because for example here {  {...state, "joinDetails": action.payload} } joinDetails suppose to be without " "

Comment: @HagaiHarari i changed the naming, removed quotation marks, but it still doesn't work: state set, but lobby not rerendered... So there's nothing more in my code that's obviously wrong?

Comment: If I understand correctly, all works as expected beside that if there's user a and user b joined, user b sees user a but not the other side around, correct?  If so, have you thought on adding Socket.io to the project?

Comment: I'm using Colyseus.js which is similar to socket.io and this part works fine, and also both players see each other "programatically", i just can't update the UI and player a doesn't see player b on the screen. The whole thing seems pretty strange to me.

Comment: can you upload your code to codepen or sandbox? 

because this bug seems so off!

have you tried to add { useEffect } at the Lobby triggering by change at the players data? 
what do you mean by " see each other "programatically" " ?

Comment: @HagaiHarari It would be hard to add my code to sandbox, beacause I'm using production server backend and I would need to somehow replicate that. But I have found one interesting thing: if I select the whole state instead of it's property (state.roomState), everything works (see EDIT 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my problem was here:

```
room.onStateChange((state) => {
                console.log("the room state has been updated:", state);
                // HERE DISPATCHING RECEIVED STATE
                dispatch({type: GAME_STATE, payload: state });
```

I was putting `state` to payload without destructuring/copying it to new object, thus actually only passing a reference. And of course, when changed it also changed all other references and there was nothing to compare to. The correct way is destructuring received `state` while passing it to action:

```
room.onStateChange((state) => {
                console.log("the room state has been updated:", state);
                // HERE DISPATCHING RECEIVED STATE
                dispatch({type: GAME_STATE, payload: {...state} })
```